# I cannot get my json to output correctly in html

Tags: jquery, json, object

Ideally I would like multiple objects displayed side by side or at least a way to toggle through them. The main issue is that I want to make the array more flexible and don't know how. For example if I want 100 objects I want to know the best way to generate them on the page.

```
function byId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var txt = {
    "characters": [{
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>",
            "fullName": "John Doe",
            "speci": "human male",
            "occup": "Web Personality",
            "cide": "Sleeper",
            "descr": "blah",
            "biog": "blarg",
            "allia": "chaos good",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/ban_two.jpg\"\/>"
    },

    {
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg\"/>",
            "fullName": "Jane Doe",
            "speci": "human female",
            "occup": "Movie Producer",
            "cide": "Citric",
            "descr": "bluh",
            "biog": "blurg",
            "allia": "neutral",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>"
    },

    {
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg\"/>",
            "fullName": "Canter Doma",
            "speci": "alienmale",
            "occup": "Chef",
            "cide": "Galv",
            "descr": "bleh",
            "biog": "blerg",
            "allia": "evil",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>"
    }]
};

var obj = txt;
//obj.toString();
byId("thumb").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].thumbn;
byId("fname").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].fullName;
byId("spec").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].speci;
byId("occu").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].occup;
byId("cid").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].cide;
byId("desc").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].descr;
byId("bio").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].biog;
byId("alli").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].allia;
byId("char").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].fullon;
```

Comment: It currently is unclear if your knowledge is sufficient. Please add what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj=txt;

var thumbn, fullName, speci, occup, cide, descr, biog, allia, fullon;

thumbn, fullName, speci, occup, cide, descr, biog, allia, fullon = "";

for(var i = 0,l = obj.length; i<l;i++) {
   thumbn = thumbn + " " + obj.characters[i].thumbn;
   fullName = fullName + " " + obj.characters[i].fullName;
   speci= speci + " " + obj.characters[i].speci;
   occup= occup + " " + obj.characters[i].occup;
   cide= cide + " " + obj.characters[i].cide;
   descr= descr + " " + obj.characters[i].descr;
   biog= biog + " " + obj.characters[i].biog;
   allia= allia + " " + obj.characters[i].allia;
   fullon= fullon + " " + obj.characters[i].fullon;

}


byId("thumb").innerHTML = thumbn;
byId("fname").innerHTML = fullName;
byId("spec").innerHTML = speci;
byId("occu").innerHTML = occup;
byId("cid").innerHTML = cide;
byId("desc").innerHTML = descr;
byId("bio").innerHTML = biog;
byId("alli").innerHTML = allia;
byId("char").innerHTML = fullon;
```

Comment: I am trying to apply this and I am not sure quite how?